# Pyserial | serial.read is reading also what im sending with serial.write

Tags: python, communication, pyserial, uart

I needed to write and read data with pyserial.
I'm sending the output I want with write command
and then want to check and read arrival of new data.
when I'm calling the read command it's also printing the data i have sent.

this is the code below:

```py
#on one script:
while 1:
    serial.write(str.encode("blabla111"))
    bytesToRead = serial.inWaiting()
    if bytesToRead is not 0:
    print(serial.read(bytesToRead))
    time.sleep(1)
 
#on second script:
while 1:
    serial.write(str.encode("hello222"))
    bytesToRead = serial.inWaiting()
    if bytesToRead is not 0:
    print(serial.read(bytesToRead))
    time.sleep(1)
```

```py
#print result on first script (excepting to get only :hello222)
blabla111hello222
```

What am I missing here?
I tried to use the flush command didn't help

Comment: Please reformat your code. There is an option to add code (brackets button) and you have to properly indent it in order to be displayed properly, you can preview before posting.

Comment: What is the hardware setup of the serial ports you're using?  Possibly the data lines going in each direction are shorted together.

Comment: hi  @jasonharper thanks for your answer. this is the setup:

`ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200) `
#and 
`ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 115200)`
I have two hardware connected to 2 different usb port on the same computer

Comment: I have tried this on 2 computers and the result is the same

Comment: How are the two USB adapters connected on the RS232 side? Can you try a simple loopback rx<>tx for each adapter? Do you have hardware connection to the RS232 - could it be echoning what is sent?

Comment: Hi guys problems solved!
The HW engineer shorted the TX and Rx together. Don't know the reason will check it out. thanks everyone!